# Why is System.Drawing and System.EnterpriseServices in default asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Can anyone tell me why is System.Drawing and System.EnterpriseServices include in the default asp.net mvc 2 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a default project template. The C# compiler will automatically remove any unused referenced from the resulting assembly. I guess they are included in the default project template in order to make it easier to access GDI+ and COM+ out of the box.